# append null data in existing columns python

Tags: python

I am taking data from API, searching with a unique id (123,321,431), if id available in this will print the result with id details, and if id not available it suppose to append the data with id and columns details.

```
data =  {logs :["id" : "123" ,"name":"jhon" ,"age":"30", "id":321","name":"steve","age":"35"]}
```

\note --431 - not available in input data

---

```
r= [123,321,431]
                                                                                         
ftr_lst = []
                                                                                          
for ftrid in r:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    r = request.get("http://r")                                                                                                                                             
    j_data = r.json()                                                                                                                                                              
    logs= j_data.get('logs',[])                                                                                                                                                                                    
    if logs:                                                                                                                                                                              
        for log in logs: ft_lst.append(log)                                                                                                                            
    else:                                                                                                                                                                             
        ftr_notfounda.append(ftr_lst)
                                                                              
json_str = json.dumps(ftr_lst)
```

actual output:

```
id                              name                      age
                                                                                                
123                             jhon                      30
                                                                                                
321                             steve                     35
```

expected output :

```
id                                     name                     age
                                                                                                
123                                    jhon                     30
                                                                                                
321                                    steve                    35
                                                                                                
431                                     nan                     nan
```

Comment: Please pay attention to proper code-formatting. See [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You don't show how you get your current output. Please show the relevant code.